# How is a uuid column ordered in ORDER BY?

Tags: postgresql

How is a `uuid` column ordered when used with `ORDER BY`? Is it based on its string representation? I can't seem to find any documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This function [compares UUIDs](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/uuid.c;h=f73c695878d1bb3e6e061e48ba450e5188221759;hb=HEAD) in PostgreSQL:

```c
/* internal uuid compare function */
static int
uuid_internal_cmp(const pg_uuid_t *arg1, const pg_uuid_t *arg2)
{
    return memcmp(arg1->data, arg2->data, UUID_LEN);
}
```

So UUIDs are compared lexically byte for byte using the binary values.

Comment: Am I right to say the a byte for byte comparison of a UUID produces the same result as a string comparison?

Comment: Actually, yes, that should be the case.